# MVC C# ActionLink with multiple "news"

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

How do I correct this so that the ActionLink reverts to `http://localsite/forum/index/4` (where 4 is defined by the parent_id as shown below):

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Forum", new { @class = "btn"}, new{ @id=ViewBag.parent_id })
```

Currently it reverts to:

```
http://localhost:53731/Forum?class=btn
```

Thanks for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just invert the two last parameters :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Forum",  new{ @id=ViewBag.parent_id }, new { @class = "btn"})
```

routeValues should come before htmlAttributes

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dd504972%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi - that adds the correct class, but now loses the index and parent_id, ie: http://localsite/Forum - no /index/4 - thanks, Mark

Comment: @fixit are your sure that ViewBag.parent_id is set to 4 ? Your routes are ok ?

Comment: @fixit maybe try first to set it manually `new{@id=4}` then test with ViewBag.

Comment: Hi - you're correct - if I hard code it, it works - must be in my controller setting the ViewBag - thank you, I'll mark as answer when SO allows.  Mark

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have the arguments reversed.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Forum", new{@id=ViewBag.parent_id }, new { @class = "btn"})
```